# Is there a way to use `set_index` with method chaining?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way that I can call `set_index(...)` while method chaining a pandas dataframe? Instead of the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]}, index=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
df = df.set_index(df.index.astype(int))
```

I am looking to integrate the `set_index` into a chain, e.g. like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]}, index=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]).set_index(lambda x: x.index.astype(int))
```

(which runs into an error).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You won't be able directly via `set_index`, since it takes an array-like of labels, not a callable. Transforming the index won't work, since its taking that as the label, and fails to identify it in the columns. Rename does take a callable though, as in jezrael's answer :) so that could be a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rename` with `int`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]}, index=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]).rename(index=int)
```

What working same like:

```
print (pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]}, index=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]).rename(int))

1  1
2  2
3  3
```

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it simpler just do:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
```

This wouldn't make a copy of your data while `df.set_index()` does.

Comment: OP need chaining.